# Azure management library for website dashboard data

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am working on project which collects the azure website usage data.
Using Microsoft Azure Management Libraries 2.0.0 ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/2.0.0 ).

In one method of this library getting error:
Method: websiteManagementClient.WebSites.GetUsageMetrics(webspacename, websitename)

This method is working for websites having "H1 Free" App service plan not for "S1 Standard".

Is there any way to resolve this issue?
or is there any alternate way to get the azure website dashboard data (data like live - Data Out, File System Storage, Memory Usage etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries is the old library, and its use should be avoided (it is not well maintained). Instead, please use the newer Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites, which is based on the new Azure ARM API.

You can find a full sample [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/tree/master/ManagementLibrarySample).

Specifically, getting quotas looks like this:

```
CsmUsageQuotaCollection quotas = await _websiteClient.Sites.GetSiteUsagesAsync(rgName, siteName);
foreach (var quota in quotas.Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"  {quota.Name.Value}: {quota.CurrentValue} {quota.Unit}");
}
```

Comment: I tried running sample code but getting error: AuthenticationFailed: The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxx' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later.

Comment: That sounds like it may be an issue with your service principal. See http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/12/azure-service-principal.html for way to create it and test it,

Comment: I succeeded to get token and list of resource group but in _websiteClient.Sites.GetSiteMetricsAsync(rgName, webSiteName) getting error - Response: 400 Bad Request <Error xmlns:i="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns="schemas .microsoft.com/windowsazure"><Code>InvalidFilterValueParameter</Code><Message>Ar gument Null Parameter name: $filter</Message></Error>.

Comment: Then I added the filter getting the error as - 500 Internal server error.
I was using the filter like - _websiteClient.Sites.GetSiteMetricsAsync(rgName, webSiteName, true, "name.value eq 'CpuTime' and startTime eq '2015-12-09T00:00:00Z' and endTime eq '2014-12-11T23:59:59Z'");
Can you please help me which filter it is looking for or please share the documentation for this library.

Comment: The method is called `GetSiteUsagesAsync`, not `GetSiteMetricsAsync`, so I'm guessing you are using the wrong library. Please start by trying to make the same I shared work. It should run as is if you have a valid service principal.

Comment: Thanks for your help it's working. Can you please share me documentation link for this library?